# ESP32-CAM dropping fps

Tags: c, esp32

I'm trying to count the blinks of a LED with the ESP32-CAM AI Thinker board. I need to count a LED that blinks once every 150ms. The code part works fine, but I'm experiencing some fps drops in some points, so I have some frozen frames and then the counting is wrong.

How can I have a smoother capture of the ESP32-CAM so that I don't lose any frames of the LED blinking?

Comment: Do you do on-board image processing or send frames somewhere else? How long does it take to process image on board? What resolution do you use? Also please embed your code into question so people would not play guessing games and do not lose the time on extra questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that I can think of:

**1. Find the source of the issue**

Why are these frames freezing? Is it the camera board itself, or is it something on the ESP32 itself? Perhaps there is some FreeRTOS task running on the ESP32 (e.g. BlueTooth or WiFi) which occasionally requires CPU and causes disp in performance.

Run `idf.py menuconfig` to check if:

- your CPU is running at maximum speed
- you have BlueTooth/WifiEnabled
- ...

**2. Extrapolate the missing data**

With this approach, you'd first detect the frame drops, and measure the amount of frames dropped. It is only an approximation though:

When you then calculate the LED blink count, take the average measured blinks from the last second (or whichever timeframe that is suitable) and fill in the missing blinks with this this data.